# Match a genomic position using a regex

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

I need help with building a regular expression for the following types of strings, I'm using Python, but a generic regex will do...

```
chr1:82137-81236
X  2Mb  6Mb
chr4:87K 1000K
```

I started one, but I can't get it to work for everything I need:

```
(CHR)*\s*([0-9]{1,2}|X|Y|MT)\s*(-|:)?\s*(\d+)\s*(MB|M|K)?\s*(-|:)?\s*(\d+)\s*(MB|M|K)?
```

It will match situations where I don't want it to, for example:

```
CHR33   -     12   3
```

is matched, but not the way I want:

```
Group 1.    CHR
Group 2.    33
Group 3.    -
Group 4.    12
Group 5.     
Group 6.     
Group 7.    3
Group 8.
```

What I would like is the following groups returned:

```
Group 1: CHR or nothing

Group 2: The chromosome value (1-20,X,Y,MT)

Group 3: The separator between chromosome and first position

Group 4: The numeric portion of the first position

Group 5: The numeric quantifier (M,Mb,K) or nothing if none

Group 6: The separator between position1 and position2

Group 7: The numeric portion of the second position

Group 8: The numeric quantifier (M,Mb,K) or nothing if none
```

The pseudo-regex should look like:

```
(CHR)(1-20|MT|X|Y)(delimiter \s*|-|:)(pos1 numeric)(pos1 quantifier)(delimiter \s*|-|:)(pos2 numeric)(pos2 quantifier)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the regex to allow for an empty match as well (whitespace added for readability):

```
(CHR|)*\s*              # CHR or nothing
([0-9]{1,2}|X|Y|MT)\s*  # Chromesome value
(-|:)?\s*               # Separator
(\d+)\s*                # Numeric portion of 1st position
(MB|M|K|)?\s*           # Numeric quantifier or nothing
(-|:|)?\s*              # Separator b/w position 1 and position 2 or nothing
(\d+|)\s*               # Numeric portio of the 2nd position or nothing
(MB|M|K|)?              # Numeric quantifier or nothing
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/tD8oP3)

Comment: Very tidy fix, +1 :) @mattjvincent you can use that tidy format in Python by adding the `(?x)` flag at the top or `re.VERBOSE` in your options.